# Type generated from string class name not recognized in newing of the same type

Tags: generics

I have some vb.net code that takes a string version of a class name, finds the type in the assemblies and uses that type to create an instance of a generic list of that type using CreateInstance. The code is below at the very bottom. My problem is that I want to make this totally generic so it will work with any type that is passed in as a string name of the type.

The created generic type Ty has the same type as One.Two.Three.MyClass (without quotes around it) if I use gettype with both Ty and One.Two.Three.MyClass  in the watch window so it seems they are exactly the same. However when I try to use type Ty to new a new instance of the type, the compiler tells me Type Ty is not defined. If I replace Ty with One.Two.Three.MyClass (no quotes around it) the compiler accepts it as follows and the code runs fine; the use of Ty is the problem in the code at the very bottom:

```
  list.Add(New ALLMEDS.EMR.Report.MUListData(lxRow("FirstName"), lxRow("LastName"), lxRow("ChartNumber"), lxRow("DOB"), lxRow("Reason")))
```

Here is the complete code below that is giving me a problem. The use of Ty in the first two lines compiles and runs fine; it is only in the "newing" of the class that it causes trouble.

```
 Dim Ty As Type = FindType("One.Two.Three.MyClass")
    Dim list As IList = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType(Ty)), IList)



    If lxDS.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            For Each lxRow As DataRow In lxDS.Tables(0).Rows
            (THE LINE BELOW CAUSES THE COMPILE ERROR:Type Ty is not defined)
list.Add(New Ty(lxRow("FirstName"), lxRow("LastName"), lxRow("ChartNumber"), lxRow("DOB"), lxRow("Reason")))
            Next
    End If

    evtShowReport(lxParameter, list)
```

Comment: So what trouble does it cause? It would help if you'd show a [mcve] which we can just copy/paste/compile/run and see the issue.

Comment: As far as the trouble, it's in the code. If you look at the second code block you'll see: (THE LINE BELOW CAUSES THE COMPILE ERROR:Type Ty is not defined)

Comment: Ah. It would have been a lot clearer if that had been away from the code, ideally quoting the error message... A complete example we can run for ourselves would still make it easier to help you...

Comment: As far as a verifiable example, I changed the name of the class in findtype since I didn't want to advertise where I work. If had left the name as it was I can be sure that you don't have that class on your machine so that line wouldn't run. and neither would the "list.add" line because the parameters for the new instance would have to match the fields of class that, on your end, can't be determined. That, to my mind, kills the idea of creating something you can just run. It is only the "list.add" line that causes the error: Type Ty is not defined. Ty causes no error in the first two lines.

Comment: In the first two lines, it's being used as a variable, not the name of the type. I see now that that's the problem. In C# you certainly can't call a constructor like that, and it looks like you can't in VB either. Note that there's really nothing stopping you creating a complete example. It doesn't have to be the same class as in your production code - it can be another class which is part of the example. (Or frankly something in the BCL...)

Comment: Basically, you need to call the constructor via reflection. Look at Type.GetConstructor.

Comment: Thanks I will look at that. Ty is a type so, even though it's a variable it's still a type. But I may be missing the point.

Comment: No, Ty *isn't* a type. It's a variable whose value is a reference to a Type object, but that's a very, very different thing. String is the name of a type. Guid is the name of a type. Object is the name of a type. Ty is the name of a variable. The set of things you can do with variables is very different from the set of things you can do with types.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're treating the token `Ty` as if it were the name of a type. It's not - it's the name of a variable. The type of that variable is `Type`, but it's still a variable. Variables and type names are entirely different things, and you can't treat them as if they were the same thing.

You've already taken account of that in your second line of code - if you'd tried to write:

```
Dim list as IList = new List(Of Ty)
```

that would have the same kind of error - because generic type arguments have to be names of types (or type parameters).

Likewise, when you try to call a constructor with `New`, you have to specify the name of a type (or a type parameter constrained to have a parameterless constructor). Aside from anything else, that's how the compiler can check that the constructor you're trying to call exists - because it knows which type you're talking about *at compile time*.

If you only have a *variable* whose value is a `Type` reference, the compiler can't check anything - so you have to use reflection. You could either call [`Type.GetConstructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [`TypeInfo.GetConstructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx) in the modern reflection API), or call [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) and let it figure out the appropriate constructor at execution time. So for example, you could use:

```
list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(Ty, lxRow("FirstName"), lxRow("LastName"), lxRow("ChartNumber"), lxRow("DOB"), lxRow("Reason")))
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. As you can tell generics are not my forte. I can see what you're saying now. This is the kind of thing that requires doing it for a while and I haven't. I'll put this all together. Thanks again.

Comment: @NeilNewton: This isn't really about generics - you'd have had exactly the same problem back in .NET 1.0, before generics existed. It's about reflection vs compile-time information. But yes, I'm sure you'll get there :)